# z/OS mainframe SFTP setting platform specific options

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

Interfacing with z/OS mainframe SFTP requires setting transfer mode and some other parameters.  Using WinSCP it can be done as such:

```
open sftp://user:password@ip
ls /+mode=text
```

It seems that I have a choice of using `Renci.SshNet.SftpClient` or `Renci.SshNet.SshClient`.  `SftpClient` doesn't seem to have a way to issue any commands that are not built in transfer related.  While `SshClient` seems to be for issuing any commands but not specifically for upload/downloading files.  What is the best way to go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If WinSCP scripting works for you, you can use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) for your .NET project.

There's even a [guide for converting WinSCP script to WinSCP .NET assembly code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_from_script).

Using it you will find that the equivalent code would use [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory):

```cs
session.ListDirectory("/+mode=text");
```

Though contrary to SSH.NET, WinSCP .NET assembly is not a native .NET assembly, so it's use is more limited.

---

With SSH.NET, the code is actually rather similar, with use of `SftpClient.ListDirectory`:

```cs
sftpClient.ListDirectory("/+mode=text");
```